# ggplot2 each group consists of only one observation

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the graph using ggplot2

So I have the following dataframe:

```
   iter        se perf name
1    V1 0.6463573 12.8    e
2    V2 0.3265986 16.8    e
3    V3 0.2333333 19.1    e
4    V4 0.1000000 19.9    e
5    V5 0.0000000 20.0    e
6    V1 0.7483315 12.6    f
7    V2 0.6333333 16.3    f
8    V3 0.6798693 18.8    f
9    V4 0.2236068 19.5    f
10   V5 0.1000000 19.9    f
```

and I am trying to plot it in the format similar to this [page](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_%28ggplot2%29/) (under Line graphs).

So here is the code for plotting:

```
pd <- position_dodge(.1)
ggplot(df, aes(x=iter, y=perf, colour=name)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=perf-se, ymax=perf+se), width=.1, position=pd) +
  geom_line(position=pd) +
  geom_point(position=pd)+
  ylim(0, 20)
```

and it is working nicely: [image], except that I want these dots to be connected. I tried to add `group=1` or `group=name` to this part `aes(x=iter, y=perf, colour=name)` but it did not help.

I also get these warnings:

```
ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead
ymax not defined: adjusting position using y instead
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

After looking in the internet, I found that the first two are due to position_dodge, but I think it is because of the ggplot, the third one is actually because of my disconnected points.

Any ideas how to connect them?

Comment: Define ymin and ymax in the "global" aesthetic mapping to avoid the other warnings.

Comment: Just move the content of the `geom_errorbar` `aes` to the `ggplot` `aes`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to adjust the group aesthetic, replace :

```
   geom_line(position=pd)
```

by

```
  geom_line(position=pd,aes(group=name))
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

check whether the data type is factor by using `is.factor(x)`, if it is `TRUE`, then use `as.integer` function.